# Issue with checking if current date is bigger than what's stored

Tags: php, mysql

So the issue currently is the code works fine, however the second the month resets id goes from May to June the code will no longer work because It's looking for if it's greater, and as 1st is not greater than 31st it has an issue, it's not looking at the month or year, just the day..

EXAMPLE: Database stores 31/05/2016 as $reward.
In this example $current would output at 03/06/2016

```
  <?php
       $reward1 = str_replace('/', '-', $reward);
       $stored = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($reward1. ' + 1 days'));
       $current = date('d/m/Y');
       if ($reward < $current) { ?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
           $(window).load(function(){
               $('#redeem1').modal('show');
           });
         </script>

     <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: You are checkin if a strtotime value is higher than a date time string. Strtotime is a integer value and the string is a string. Try this: `if ($reward < strtotime($current)) {`

Comment: Sorry you are checking strings against strings. Do this : `if (strtotime($reward) < strtotime($current)) {` now both values are integer and seconds since 1970

Comment: Also your $reward becomes $reward1 that becomes $stored, then you use $reward (the first value) in the if. Is that not supposed to be $stored?

Comment: If you do need to compare date strings they should be in the format "yyyy\mm\dd" - year first then 2 digit month then 2 digit day. But as the others have said conversion to integer value is preferred.

Comment: You could compare dates as strings if you use "Ymd" with intval as the numbers will always be higher at a later date. But strtotime is far better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a few errors in your code as posted above in comments.
See if it works.

```
$reward1 = str_replace('/', '-', $reward);
$stored = strtotime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($reward1. ' + 1 days')));
$current = strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));

// now both values are in integer
// using d/m/y is not a standard datetime, php assumes it is american m/d/y. 
   if ($stored < $current) { ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(window).load(function(){
           $('#redeem1').modal('show');
       });
     </script>

 <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: I used your code from the comments and fixing the $stored (Not sure how I messed that up so BAD! but thank you very much your comment fixed it! :)

Comment: No problem. Sometimes you need to take a step back to see the obvious errors such as using the wrong variable. Has happedned a few times for me too. :-)

Comment: @UKTSLiam also take not of the comment I made in the code here about d/m/y dates. It will probably cause issues again if you keep using it.

Comment: I will take a look at swapping it over :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings. This is wrong.

Take a look at the excellent Carbon library for the **best practice** way to achieve this. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

```
$reward = Carbon::parse($reward);
$now = Carbon::now();

if ($reward->lt($now)) {
  // Do something
}
```